# Linking (anchor tag) inside of a CSS file

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to link inside of a CSS file, such as adding a table of contents at the head to which you could then click on an item and much like an anchor tag, skip down to the appropriate place in the CSS file?

In lengthy CSS files, this would be quite useful.

Comment: Nope. A CSS files contains CSS. CSS doesn't have any link mechanism.

Comment: CSS files are plain text and have no linking capability

Comment: That's a job for your text editor. 1/ Different from what you're asking but that may help: Atom minimap + [minimap-highlight-selected](https://atom.io/packages/minimap-highlight-selected). 2/ Or if you label your TOC item in a way that can only be found twice (as a TOC item and as a target), then double-click it, Ctrl-F (it's autoselected as your new search term) and Enter ⇒ you'll jump to the target.

Comment: It was just a curiosity. I was pretty sure the answer was no, but figured I'd toss it out there and see what the guru's thought of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. And you don't really need it instead of doing it you can break your file into multiple smaller CSS file and then create a main.css file and import the files into that main file. You can use import like this:

```
@import "navigation.css"; /* Using a string */

or

@import url("navigation.css"); /* Using a url */
```

For example you should have header.css, footer.css, blocks.css, and global.css for your global classes.

Comment: Unless something has changed recently with @import that I am unaware of, this will prevent the browser from downloading the files in parallel and so increase your page load time.

Comment: When you deliver your project to the real environment, you should never deliver it with that main.css file. instead, you should bundle and minify it. It means you have it only on a development environment. On the live environment, it is only one file which is minified.

Comment: HTTP/2 but it's probably not implied by this answer. Or need some workflow like [postcss-import](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import)

Comment: Then no is the answer. While I hear what you're saying about breaking it down into multiple css files, sometimes that's not always the route one wants to go, for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to do this with some custom software ...

But, a better solution is to create better css with good naming convention like : https://csswizardry.com/2015/08/bemit-taking-the-bem-naming-convention-a-step-further/ or https://cssguidelin.es/ .

This kind of architecture will give you readable css project with smaller css file.

Comment: Was just curious if there was a faster / different way to search though a file when looking for a specific class in a lengthy css file. Agreed, one should never skimp on good naming conventions. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -2):

In classic ASP I used a hack which is only helpful for developing purposes using ctrl+click (in most of design softwares to follow anchor links in design view) but all extra codes disappears on runtime and a pure stylesheet will be pushed to the client.

this is **Style.asp**:

```
<%response.contenttype="text/css"%>
<%if 1=2 then%>
      <a href="#section2">go to section 2</a>
<%end if%>

table{
 border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

<%if 1=2 then%>
   <a id="section2"></a>
<%end if%>

td{
 padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: For who voted down: CSS is not a word document or a web page. Are you looking for a user friendly web page with nice table of content?! Please leave a comment or an answer rather than "**it is impossible**".